# Probably base64 encoded WKB - Reading in QGis/ArcGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, well-known-text, well-known-binary

I have a probably base64 encoded WKB string. How would I load that feature represented by the string into QGis or ArcGIS?

I found the QGis QuickWKT plugin, but that does not handle my base64 encoded string.

I have some Python programming skills.

Get your own WKB from http://nibis.lbeg.de/net3/public/ogc.ashx?Service=WMS&PKGID=22&cardo3SessionGuid=C3_2d80a40c-529e-4574-912b-53a3858b173c&layers=L160&query_layers=L160&width=1&request=GetFeatureInfo&height=1&srs=EPSG%3A31467&version=1.1.1&bbox=3585999%2C5743699%2C3586001%2C5743701&info_format=text%2Fplain&y=1&x=1 if you like.

Comment: where is the wkb in the link, after GEOM_R1 ?

Comment: Yeah, after GEOM_R1

Comment: ...at least I hope this is WKB/WKT. Am not sure, though. Will test further.

Comment: It is the response of a WMS service and not a WKB

Comment: So the string decodes to an image file?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string object, you can use the `.decode()` method on it to get it from base64 to the original string. For example,

```
shape_base64 = "BXsAAAEEKwAAACL99gXlXEt...<omitted for brevity>...gAAAAABAAAA/////wAAAAAD"
shape_string = shape_base64.decode("base64")
```

From there you can use the standard methods. I don't know about QGIS, but in ArcGIS you can use the [`FromWKB` function](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v0000008n000000) to get an arcpy geometry object, or if you're using [a da cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/InsertCursor/018w0000000t000000/) you can use the `SHAPE@WKB` token as a column name to directly insert the decoded WKB string.

Comment: For QGIS you can use the `QgsGeometry.fromWkb()` function

`shape_string = '\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10@'`
`geom = QgsGeometry()`
`geom.fromWkb(shape_string)`

Comment: Which import should be used for QgsGeometry? It gives me SyntaxError: invalid syntax